# How to get background page from a window opened in chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

The app opens a popup from the background page . The popup that opens, has js files that access some variables of background page . but when it tries to access,

chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage().variable_name it gives a "undefined" value

**background.html contains**

```
  chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function() {
return chrome.windows.create({
  url: "../popup.html",
  type: 'popup',
  height: 500,
  width: 200
}, function(window) {
  return console.log("opening a window");
});
});
```

**manifest.json**

```
{
"name": "app name",
"version": "0.0.2",
"manifest_version": 2,
"minimum_chrome_version": "23",
"icons": {
    "16": "images/background-16.png",
    "48": "images/background-48.png",
    "128": "images/background-120.png"
},
 "background": {
  "page": "background.html"
},
"browser_action": {
  "default_icon": "images/background-16.png"

},
"default_locale": "en",
"permissions": [
  "storage",
"pushMessaging",
"notifications",
"tts",
```

]
  }

Comment: "`background.html`" is really a js file, yes?  And what is in `popup.html`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use `getBackgroundPage()`, you have to call background's variables in a callback function.

For example:

In `background.js`:

```
var cow = "mooh";
// The code to open myApp.html
```

In `myApp.js` (linked to `myApp.html`):

```
chrome.runtime.getBackgroundPage(function (backgroundPage) {
    console.log(backgroundPage.cow); // Displays "mooh".
});
```

Comment: Another small thing to note is that the method which you want to access has to be in the global `window` scope of the background script. So if you simply declare a function with `const myFunc = () => {}` (in `background.js`), then it won't be visible with `getBackgroundPage()`.

Comment: Another important note - If you're using Webpack, it will wrap your global function/variable in a module and you won't be able to access them via `getBackgroundPage()`. You can use `global.cow = "mooh"` to get around this.

Comment: It gives me `undefined` in `popup.js`

Comment: @Volatil3 - were you able to solve this? I, too, am getting undefined